# dealing with nested quotes in bash scripts redux

Tags: scripting

I want to construct a bash script which contains nested double quotes.    I've tried all of the usual tricks, in particular  `rprint` which everybody recommends. But nothing I've tried works. 
    In particular, `rprint -v name "%q "` lets me nest quotes but I then can't deal with the `\`'s it puts in front of the quotes.   Finally I settled on this extremely crude kludge:

```
shCommand=`echo !ssh -p $othPort!`
execThis=`echo rsync -e $sshCommand etc etc | tr '!' '"'`
eval $execThis
```

Thus execThis is what I want, i.e.,

```
 rsync -e "ssh -p XXXX" etc etc
```

But there has to be a better way to do this since a) it's *extremely* crude and b) it won't work if I need the ! in following line --- there seems to be *no* special character that `bash` never uses.     Could somebody tell me what a real bash programmer would do in this instance?    Thanks very much for any advice

Comment: In my opinion that is not a good problem description. You talk about problems instead of showing the code and the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
othPort=XXXX
shCommand="ssh -p $othPort"
cmdline=(rsync -e "$shCommand" etc etc)
"${cmdline[@]}"
```

```
othPort=XXXX
shCommand="ssh -p $othPort"
cmdline="rsync -e \"$shCommand\" etc etc"
eval "$cmdline"
```

Comment: Thanks!     Such a simple solution!